# Não consigo usar um atributo iniciado com o constructor no typescript

Tags: typescript, construtor

Estou usando typescript, typeorm, postgres e express;
Estou tentando iniciar a classe TeamRepository criada por mim através de um construtor dentro da classe TeamController, só que dentro dos métodos que utilizam essa classe eu recebo que o this.teamRepo é undefinded

```
class TeamController {

    private teamRepo: TeamRepository;

    constructor() {
        const repo = new TypeOrmTeamRepo(); 
        this.teamRepo = new TeamRepository(repo);
        // console.log(this.teamRepo) ==> recebo certo
    }

    public async addTeam(request: Request, response: Response) {
        try {
            // console.log(this.teamRepo) ==> recebo undefined
            const { teamName } = request.body;
           
            const newTeam = await this.teamRepo.create(teamName);
            console.log(newTeam);

            return response.json(newTeam)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return response.status(404).json(error);
        }
    }
};
```

no entanto, se eu der console.log() dentro do construtor, ele retorna certo, já se eu tentar dar o console.log() dentro do método eu recebo undefined;
E por algum motivo se eu criar a classe TeamRepository fora do TeamController ou dentro do método, ele funciona corretamente, desse jeito:

```
const teamRepo: IBaseTeamRepo = new TeamRepository(new TypeOrmTeamRepo()); //aqui

class TeamController {
    public async addTeam(request: Request, response: Response) {
        try {
            const teamRepo: IBaseTeamRepo = new TeamRepository(new TypeOrmTeamRepo()); //ou aqui 
            const { teamName } = request.body;

            const newTeam = await teamRepo.create(teamName););
            console.log(newTeam);

            return response.json(newTeam)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return response.status(404).json(error);
        }
    }
};
```

Segue o código dos repositórios:

```
class TeamRepository implements IBaseTeamRepo {
    private repository: IBaseTeamRepo;

    constructor(repository: IBaseTeamRepo) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public async create(team: BaseTeamModel): Promise<any> {
        return await this.repository.create(team);
    }
}
```

```
export default class TypeOrmTeamRepo implements IBaseTeamRepo {
    public async create(newTeamName: string): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const teamRepo = await getRepository(Team);
            console.log(newTeamName);

            const newTeam = await teamRepo.create({
                teamName: newTeamName
            });

            await teamRepo.save(newTeam);
    
            return newTeam;
        } catch(error) {
            return error;
        }
    }
};
```

e das interfaces:

```
interface BaseTeamModel {
    teamName: string;
};

interface IBaseTeamRepo {
    create(BaseTeamModel): Promise<any>;
};

export {
    BaseTeamModel,
    IBaseTeamRepo,
}
```

Comment: bom já tentou passar teamRepo nos parâmetros da função addTeam ?

Comment: Você diz chamar o addTeam com um parâmetro?, mas como faço isso se no router()  ele não tem nenhum parâmetro

Comment: Seu projeto está compilando normalmente? As classes estão sendo exportadas para uso externo? Como é usada a classe do controlador? Mesmo sua pergunta tendo bastante código, não é possível produzir o erro, dê uma olhada em [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era no jeito que eu estava chamando o método no router,

Antes estava:

```
const teamController = new TeamController();

const adminRoutes = express.Router();

adminRoutes.post("/", teamController.addTeam);
```

E era só mudar para:

```
const teamController = new TeamController();

const adminRoutes = Router();

adminRoutes.post("/", (request: Request, response: Response) => {
        return teamController.addTeam(request, response);
});
```